# is it possible to log all thrown exceptions during program execution?

Tags: c#

I have C# application. I can compile it in debug mode, with any flags etc. if required.

After some point it doesn't function properly (significant slow-down, partly hangs etc. etc.)

Obviously something goes wrong. As a first try I want to see complete list of all exceptions that hapened anywhere during program execution (caught and uncaught). Is it possible? I know there is an option in VS that allows me to "brekpoint" at certain exception. But I don't want to "breakpoint", instead I want to "log" all happened exceptions so I can analyze them later.

Comment: `Console.Error.WriteLine(exception.ToString());` and redirect standard error to a file?

Comment: @Wug should I add this string after each line of my application?

Comment: No, just in catch blocks.  `exception` is the name of the exception you catch.

Comment: @Wug so I have to scan thru all catch blocks of my application and modify them?

Comment: @javapowered - yes, unless everything percolates back to some central point and you want to stacktrace from there.....

Comment: You'd be much better off using breakpoints.  Is there some reason you don't want to?

Comment: @Wug i don't know which Exception to breakpoint. breakpointing all exceptions also not possible as there are a lot of cases where Exception is "legal". also application shouldn't stop while executing to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You may be trying to use the wrong tool for the job here.  If you're trying to debug slow-downs you should consider a profiler tool.  If there are partial hangs, a well-placed breakpoint should help you see why.  Trying to log all exceptions is going to generate a lot of noise because most exceptions that occur in a program get handled and recovered from.

Comment: @PeteBaughman it's ok to have noise. I have time to analyze noise. and in most cases noise is easy to filter out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use **UnhandledException** in you application if you are not sure where exceptions can occur possibly.

The UnhandledException event handles uncaught exceptions thrown from the main UI thread. The ThreadException event handles uncaught exceptions thrown from non-UI threads.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{      
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
    //... do something ...      
}

static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
      System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine((e.ExceptionObject as Exception).Message, "Unhandled UI Exception");
      // here you can log the exception ...
}
```

I have used [Trace class on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.aspx) for logging:

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace
```

This includes listeners that listen for your `Trace()` methods, and then write to a log file/output window/event log, ones in the framework that are included are `DefaultTraceListener`, `TextWriterTraceListener` and the `EventLogTraceListener`. It allows you to specify levels (Warning,Error,Info) and categories.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: This answer is pretty good, but I wouldnt recommend MessageBox.Show in the handlers.  I would hate to forget to remove those message boxes in production code.  It would be better to just log.

Comment: This does partially answer your question.  This will allow you to log the uncaught exceptions.  The other piece is that in your caught exceptions, you need to add code to log the exception.

Comment: This is just an example code, obviously this should be used for logging and as per requirement.

Comment: can I use this in Console application?

Comment: Sure you can use the code in Console as well, see my simplified edited code in the answer.

Comment: @FurqanSafdar should I add "Application_ThreadException" as well?

Answer (score 3):

Frankly,  You shouldn't use exceptions for this.  What you need is to "instrument" the application to log critical activities within the code, with date time stamps, so that after something goes wrong, you can review the chronological logs and see what, (and where) the code is either failing to do what is expected, or taking longer than it should.  Check out [Microsoft Logging Application Blo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647183.aspx)ck, or [log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/)

In general, the proper use of Exceptions should be limited to cases where the application, (or module, or subroutine/function), cannot successfully complete whatever function it has been designed to provide.  Exceptions should be logged as well, but exceptions should not be used to track anything other than critical failures.  If the code cannot recover from a failure, it should, in most cases, simply cause the app to stop.

In fact, most of time when something goes wrong and an Exception is thrown, (except for the most trivial problems), the information available at the point where the exception was thrown is only the very first step in diagnosing the issue. What happened in the code execution path prior to that is more often where the real issue is...

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question as asked, you will likely need to (at least partially) create your own debugger that will attach to your process and record all unhandled and handled exceptions. [This is probably where you want to start](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19621).  Also, here is the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404484.aspx) for the debugging interface.

This should let you do exactly what Visual Studio does when you go to Debug -> Exceptions and check the box to break when an exception is thrown.  The only difference is that instead of stopping execution, you should be able to record information about where the exception is thrown (and I think the type of exception).  The first thing you'll notice is that this is extremely complicated.  Hopefully the mdbg sample is close enough to what you need that you can just tweak it slightly.

I will also disclaim that this probably isn't the best way to solve the underlying problem that you're trying to solve.  If there are unhandled exceptions in your program, you probably shouldn't need any extra help finding them.  They should bubble up to the surface unless the code does things like this:

```
try
{
    . . . Some operation
}
catch(Exception){ } //Muddle on through - Very Bad!!!
```

If the issue is that there are handled exceptions that aren't getting handled properly, then the above approach won't do much to help you narrow down what the problem is either

Comment: well creating my own debugger is not something i'm looking for :) i do need much more simpler solutions...

Comment: I agree, but if you want a simpler solution, you're going to have to simplify your problem statement too.